# HTML tags won't accept my CSS classes when changed via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change the classes of certain HTML elements when clicked on using JavaScript, but having some trouble.

Here's the JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#subnav li a').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.addClass('highlight').siblings('a').removeClass('highlight');
 });
});
```

Here's the corresponding HTML:

```
<div id="subnav">
    <ul id="subnav-ul">
        <li><a href="javascript:;" class="highlight">Click 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">Click 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">Click 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The single CSS class is as follows:

```
.highlight {
border-left: 4px solid rgba(51,102,255,.6);
color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

lets dont forget about `find('a')` output is `array`

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#subnav li a').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('highlight');
    $(this).parent().siblings('li').find('a').each(function(){
      $(this).removeClass('highlight');
    });
  });
});
```

[See on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J9M8p/)

Answer (score 4):

The anchors are not siblings, they are within LI elements that are siblings

```
$('#subnav li a').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('highlight')
           .closest('li')
           .siblings('li')
           .find('a')
           .removeClass('highlight');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#subnav li a').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('highlight');
    $(this).parent().siblings('li').find('a').removeClass('highlight');

});
```

Try the above code.

Answer (score 0):

The anchors are not siblings to one another.  They are cousins.

Answer (score 0):

It's not removing the highlight class because you have:

```
$this.addClass('highlight').siblings('a')
```

when it should be:

```
$this.parent().siblings('li').find('a')
```

Example

**http://jsfiddle.net/DU7V8/1/**

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$(function() {
 $('#subnav li a').click(function(){
    $('#subnav li a.highlight').removeClass('highlight'); //remove class in all links
    $(this).addClass('highlight'); //add class in current link
 });
});
```

`$(function(){});` is the shortcut to  `$(document).ready(function() {});`

I hope this help.